# Landscape and Longtable conflict if both are used together in a table

Tags: latex, landscape, tabular, overleaf, longtable

I have data tables that need to be put in my thesis and they have to be in landscape mode since there are more columns and the headings have to be the same in all the sheets. The compilation takes too long on overleaf. I am also using the package `threeparttable` as I want to use table notes to make one comment at the end of the table. The MWE used is given below. I want to know if the method I have used is correct. or is there a better way to do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside] 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\usepackage{rotating,caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{documnet}
    
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[ht]
        \footnotesize
            \centering
            \caption{Continuum and emission-line flux variability characteristics of Mrk 335 of the period 1978 to 1993.}
            \label{335}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc cc cc cc cc cc c }
                \toprule
                Obs. Dates 
                &  \makecell{ $\lambda_{o}$  \\ (\AA) \space}& Spectrum ID. 
                &   \makecell{  F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)} & snr & Spectrum ID. 
                &  \makecell{   F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)} & snr
                &  \makecell{   F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} 
                &   \makecell{  R$_{max}$   $\pm\ \Delta$R$_{max}$ }  
                &   \makecell{  F$_{var}$   $\pm\ \Delta$F$_{var}$ }  
                & \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}  
                &  N         \\  
                \midrule
                %% table body
                18-01-1979 / 04-02-1984     &   1350    &   SWP22205    &   6.85    $\pm$   0.14    &   5.87    &   SWP03938    &   14.59   $\pm$   0.04    &   11.91   &   7.31    $\pm$   0.04    &   2.13    $\pm$   0.04    &   15.19   $\pm$   0.07    &   1843    &   35  \\
                18-06-1990 / 19-01-1990 &   1450    &   SWP39107    &   7.3 $\pm$   0.03    &   14.3    &   SWP38051    &   13.47   $\pm$   0.13    &   10.38   &   6.76    $\pm$   0.03    &   1.85    $\pm$   0.02    &   15  $\pm$   0.13    &   149 &   27  \\
                18-01-1979 / 10-08-1990     &   1605    &   SWP39439    &   7.5 $\pm$   0.03    &   12.5    &   SWP03938    &   13.44   $\pm$   0.04    &   8.36    &   6.35    $\pm$   0.03    &   1.79    $\pm$   0.01    &   15.16   $\pm$   0.09    &   4222    &   36  \\
                18-01-1979 / 04-02-1984     &   1675    &   SWP22205    &   5.82    $\pm$   0.02    &   7.12    &   SWP03938    &   11.91   $\pm$   0.03    &   19.18   &   5.84    $\pm$   0.03    &   2.05    $\pm$   0.01    &   16.22   $\pm$   0.06    &   1843    &   38  \\
                18-01-1979 / 04-02-1984     &   1812    &   SWP22205    &   4.78    $\pm$   0.02    &   9.05    &   SWP03938    &   10.31   $\pm$   0.01    &   9.32    &   5.46    $\pm$   0.03    &   2.16    $\pm$   0.01    &   15.87   $\pm$   0.07    &   1843    &   39  \\
                31-12-1983 / 04-02-1984 &   2475    &   LWP2532 &   6.01    $\pm$   0.04    &   5.55    &   LWR17238    &   3.83    $\pm$   0.02    &   8.4 &   4.3 $\pm$   0.03    &   1.95    $\pm$   0.02    &   14.47   $\pm$   0.08    &   35  &   29  \\
                31-12-1983 / 04-02-1984 &   2625    &   LWP2532 &   4.93    $\pm$   0.02    &   8.27    &   LWR17238    &   3.09    $\pm$   0.01    &   6.37    &   4.1 $\pm$   0.03    &   2.1 $\pm$   0.01    &   13.72   $\pm$   0.06    &   35  &   36  \\
                31-12-1983 / 04-02-1984 &   2875    &   LWP2532 &   4.27    $\pm$   0.02    &   13.18   &   LWR17238    &   2.98    $\pm$   0.02    &   9.9 &   3.63    $\pm$   0.02    &   3.19    $\pm$   0.03    &   37  $\pm$   0.07    &   35  &   37  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular*}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc cc cc cc cc cc c }
                \toprule
                Obs. Dates &   \makecell{Emission \\ line} &    Spectrum ID.   
                &   \makecell{  F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)} & Spectrum No.
                &  \makecell{   F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)} 
                &  \makecell{   F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} & EW (\AA \space)
                &   \makecell{  R$_{max}$    $\pm\ \Delta$  R$_{max}$ }  
                &   \makecell{  F$_{var}$    $\pm\ \Delta$  F$_{var}$ }  
                & \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}  
                &  N         \\  
                \midrule
                %% table body
                05/07/1978 - 19/07/1990 &   Ly$\alpha$  &   SWP39252    &   99.78   $\pm$   1.05    &   SWP01919    &   29.57   $\pm$   0.01    &   64.675  $\pm$   1.03    &   195.83  &   2.96    $\pm$   0.03    &   31.86   $\pm$   0.1 &   4396    &   37  \\
                05/07/1978 - 22/01/1985 &   Si IV   &   SWP39439    &   10.47   $\pm$   0.7 &   SWP24944    &   31.18   $\pm$   0.92    &   20.83   $\pm$   0.81    &   24.44   &   2.98    $\pm$   0.22    &   25.95   $\pm$   0.86    &   2026    &   30  \\
                22/01/1985 - 30/06/1991 &   C IV    &   SWP41962    &   49.44   $\pm$   0.76    &   SWP23250    &   108.1   $\pm$   0.45    &   78.77   $\pm$   0.61    &   151.37  &   2.19    $\pm$   0.03    &   17.95   $\pm$   0.17    &   2350    &   42  \\
                30/07/1983 - 31/12/1983 &   He II   &   SWP20544    &   11.5    $\pm$   0.57    &   SWP21922    &   44.86   $\pm$   0.67    &   28.18   $\pm$   0.62    &   43.775  &   3.9 $\pm$   0.2 &   35.71   $\pm$   0.5 &   153 &   35  \\
                22/01/1985 - 18/06/1990 &   C III]  &   SWP39107    &   5.92    $\pm$   0.79    &   LWP05247    &   75.8    $\pm$   0.42    &   40.86   $\pm$   0.61    &   95.002  &   12.8    $\pm$   1.71    &   82.96   $\pm$   0.68    &   1973    &   40  \\
                04/09/1981 - 30/07/1983 &   Mg II   &   LWR11470    &   6.78    $\pm$   0.52    &   LWR16482    &   27.91   $\pm$   0.31    &   17.35   $\pm$   0.42    &   51.035  &   4.12    $\pm$   0.32    &   44.29   $\pm$   0.62    &   694 &   23  \\ 
                \bottomrule 
            \end{tabular*}
        \end{table}
    
        \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
        \setlength{\LTright}{0pt}
        \setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.3}
        \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc cc cc cc c}
        \caption{Annualized continuum and emission-line flux variability characteristics of Mrk 335. } 
        \label{annual_335}  
            \toprule
            \makecell{ $\lambda_{o}$  \\} (\AA \space) / Line
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)}  %Spectrum ID.   & 
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)}
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} 
            & EW (\AA \space)
            &   \makecell{R$_{max}$    $\pm\ \Delta$R$_{max}$ }
            &   \makecell{F$_{var}$    $\pm\ \Delta$F$_{var}$ }
            &   \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}
            &  N         \\ 
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead        
            \toprule
            \makecell{ $\lambda_{o}$ } (\AA \space) / Line
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)}  %Spectrum ID.   & 
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)}
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} 
            & EW (\AA \space)
            &   \makecell{R$_{max}$    $\pm\ \Delta$R$_{max}$ }
            &   \makecell{F$_{var}$   $\pm\ \Delta$F$_{var}$ }
            &   \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}
            &  N         \\
            \midrule
            \endhead   
            \midrule     
            \multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\textit{Continued on the next page}}
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule 
            \endlastfoot   
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1981}               &               &       &       \\      
    
    2625    &   4.59    $\pm$   0.02    &   5.19    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.89    $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.33    $\pm$   0.01    &   12.68   $\pm$   0.24    &   267 &   4   \\  
    
    2687    &   4.43    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.88    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.66    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.45    $\pm$   0.02    &   16.25   $\pm$   0.55    &   267 &   4   \\  
    
    2875    &   4.19    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.6 $\pm$   0.02    &   4.4 $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.37    $\pm$   0.01    &   13.65   $\pm$   0.24    &   267 &   4   \\  \hline
    
    Si IV   &   1.99    $\pm$   0.1 &   1.53    $\pm$   0.08    &   1.76    $\pm$   0.09    &   19.24   &   1.3 $\pm$   0.09    &   14.21   $\pm$   3.04    &   267 &   3   \\  
    C IV    &   6.13    $\pm$   0.1 &   6.41    $\pm$   0.06    &   6.27    $\pm$   0.08    &   73.39   &   1.05    $\pm$   0.02    &   2.34    $\pm$   0.85    &   267 &   3   \\  
    
    C III]  &   1.85    $\pm$   0.07    &   6.38    $\pm$   0.06    &   4.12    $\pm$   0.07    &   40.66   &   0.52    $\pm$   0.19    &   70.91   $\pm$   1.1 &   0.26    &   6   \\  
    
    Mg II   &   0.98    $\pm$   0.05    &   0.79    $\pm$   0.05    &   0.89    $\pm$   0.05    &   16.42   &   1.45    $\pm$   0.12    &   19.02   $\pm$   3.57    &   63  &   3   \\  \hline\hline
    
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1982}               &               &       &       \\      
    
    1350    &   10.57   $\pm$   0.03    &   10.58   $\pm$   0.04    &   10.58   $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.06    $\pm$   0.01    &   3.49    $\pm$   0.21    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
    
    1450    &   9.32    $\pm$   0.06    &   8.93    $\pm$   0.07    &   9.13    $\pm$   0.07    &   -   &   1.16    $\pm$   0.01    &   7.41    $\pm$   0.43    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    1605    &   10.46   $\pm$   0.06    &   9.98    $\pm$   0.06    &   10.22   $\pm$   0.06    &   -   &   1.18    $\pm$   0.01    &   8.29    $\pm$   0.32    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                
    1675    &   9.26    $\pm$   0.03    &   8.31    $\pm$   0.04    &   8.79    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   0.9 $\pm$   0.01    &   10.97   $\pm$   0.26    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                        
    1812    &   7.71    $\pm$   0.03    &   7.2 $\pm$   0.02    &   7.46    $\pm$   0.03    &   -   &   1.13    $\pm$   0.01    &   6.16    $\pm$   0.23    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                
    Si IV   &   2.38    $\pm$   0.09    &   1.97    $\pm$   0.08    &   2.18    $\pm$   0.09    &   24.88   &   1.21    $\pm$   0.07    &   9.72    $\pm$   2.32    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   6.73    $\pm$   0.08    &   6.37    $\pm$   0.07    &   6.55    $\pm$   0.08    &   87.18   &   1.16    $\pm$   0.02    &   7.79    $\pm$   0.66    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    He II   &   2.39    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.65    $\pm$   0.08    &   2.52    $\pm$   0.08    &   37.91   &   1.34    $\pm$   0.06    &   15.11   $\pm$   1.54    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C III]  &   3.29    $\pm$   0.06    &   1.08    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.19    $\pm$   0.07    &   25.5    &   3.14    $\pm$   0.22    &   60.26   $\pm$   2.12    &   0.07    &   4   \\  \hline\hline
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
    &       $\pm$       &       $\pm$       &                   &   \textbf{1985}       &       &       $\pm$       &       &       \\      
                                                                                                                    
    C III]  &   2.3 $\pm$   0.05    &   7.58    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.94    $\pm$   0.05    &   81.88   &   4.78    $\pm$   0.11    &   85.59   $\pm$   0.95    &   174 &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   7   $\pm$   0.06    &   10.81   $\pm$   0.05    &   8.91    $\pm$   0.06    &   153.07  &   1.54    $\pm$   0.01    &   23.7    $\pm$   0.41    &   174 &   3   \\  \hline \hline
                                                                                                                    
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1989}               &               &       &       \\      
                                                                                                                    
    1350    &   12.03   $\pm$   0.03    &   9.24    $\pm$   0.02    &   10.64   $\pm$   0.03    &   -   &   1.49    $\pm$   0.01    &   15.27   $\pm$   0.11    &   182 &   10  \\  
    1450    &   10.91   $\pm$   0.06    &   9.5 $\pm$   0.05    &   10.21   $\pm$   0.06    &   -   &   1.39    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.16   $\pm$   0.22    &   182 &   7   \\  
    1605    &   12.29   $\pm$   0.05    &   9   $\pm$   0.04    &   10.65   $\pm$   0.05    &   -   &   1.53    $\pm$   0.01    &   13.27   $\pm$   0.14    &   182 &   10  \\  
    1675    &   10.15   $\pm$   0.04    &   8.33    $\pm$   0.03    &   9.24    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   0.82    $\pm$   0   &   12.89   $\pm$   0.12    &   182 &   11  \\  
                                                                                                                    
    1812    &   9.87    $\pm$   0.05    &   7.44    $\pm$   0.03    &   8.66    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.63    $\pm$   0.01    &   14.18   $\pm$   0.13    &   182 &   11  \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2475    &   6.51    $\pm$   0.02    &   5.38    $\pm$   0.01    &   5.95    $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.31    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.32   $\pm$   0.14    &   182 &   6   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2625    &   5.72    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.88    $\pm$   0.01    &   5.3 $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.24    $\pm$   0.01    &   8.91    $\pm$   0.12    &   182 &   6   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2875    &   5.04    $\pm$   0.01    &   4.18    $\pm$   0.01    &   4.61    $\pm$   0.01    &   -   &   1.29    $\pm$   0   &   11.12   $\pm$   0.25    &   182 &   6   \\  \hline
                                                                                                                    
    Ly$\alpha$  &   14.37   $\pm$   0.04    &   13.2    $\pm$   0.1 &   13.79   $\pm$   0.07    &   176.69  &   1.43    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.4    $\pm$   0.22    &   182 &   9   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    Si IV   &   1.82    $\pm$   0.08    &   3.08    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.45    $\pm$   0.08    &   24.36   &   2.12    $\pm$   0.1 &   26.58   $\pm$   1.63    &   29  &   7   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   6.32    $\pm$   0.06    &   6.26    $\pm$   0.09    &   6.29    $\pm$   0.08    &   93.79   &   1.33    $\pm$   0.02    &   9.79    $\pm$   0.38    &   58  &   9   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    He II   &   3.16    $\pm$   0.08    &   4.1 $\pm$   0.05    &   3.63    $\pm$   0.07    &   42.14   &   2.24    $\pm$   0.06    &   28.59   $\pm$   0.95    &   29  &   7   \\  
            
    C III]  &   3.96    $\pm$   0.06    &   1.19    $\pm$   0.09    &   2.58    $\pm$   0.08    &   19.66   &   5.49    $\pm$   0.43    &   71.22   $\pm$   1.87    &   54  &   9   \\  
            
    Mg II   &   2.55    $\pm$   0.04    &   1.2 $\pm$   0.04    &   1.88    $\pm$   0.04    &   31.24   &   3.03    $\pm$   0.11    &   42.57   $\pm$   1.25    &   54  &   7   \\  \hline\hline
    
        \end{longtable} 
        
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \textbf{Note:}\\
     Dates of Observation correspond to the continuum flux minima and flux maxima. 
     Continuum and emission-line fluxes - minima, maxima and average are in units of 10$^{-14}$ erg/s/cm$^2$/\AA \space and 10$^{-13}$ erg/s/cm$^2$/\AA \space respectively.   
     N is the number of epochs of observations considered for computing mean continuum and emission-line fluxes and its error. F$_{Var}$ is in percentage. 
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}    
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three errors:

- no documentclass
- misspelled `\begin{document}`
- missing `\\` after the caption in the longtable

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\usepackage{rotating,caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
   
        \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
        \setlength{\LTright}{0pt}
        \setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.3}
        \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc cc cc cc c}
        \caption{Annualized continuum and emission-line flux variability characteristics of Mrk 335.      \label{annual_335}   }\\ 
            \toprule
            \makecell{ $\lambda_{o}$  \\} (\AA \space) / Line
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)}  %Spectrum ID.   & 
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)}
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} 
            & EW (\AA \space)
            &   \makecell{R$_{max}$    $\pm\ \Delta$R$_{max}$ }
            &   \makecell{F$_{var}$    $\pm\ \Delta$F$_{var}$ }
            &   \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}
            &  N         \\ 
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead        
            \toprule
            \makecell{ $\lambda_{o}$ } (\AA \space) / Line
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (min)}  %Spectrum ID.   & 
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (max)}
            &   \makecell{F$_\lambda$ $\pm\ \Delta$F$_\lambda$ \\ (avg)} 
            & EW (\AA \space)
            &   \makecell{R$_{max}$    $\pm\ \Delta$R$_{max}$ }
            &   \makecell{F$_{var}$   $\pm\ \Delta$F$_{var}$ }
            &   \makecell{$\Delta$T \\ (days)}
            &  N         \\
            \midrule
            \endhead   
            \midrule     
            \multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\textit{Continued on the next page}}
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule 
            \endlastfoot   
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1981}               &               &       &       \\      
    
    2625    &   4.59    $\pm$   0.02    &   5.19    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.89    $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.33    $\pm$   0.01    &   12.68   $\pm$   0.24    &   267 &   4   \\  
    
    2687    &   4.43    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.88    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.66    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.45    $\pm$   0.02    &   16.25   $\pm$   0.55    &   267 &   4   \\  
    
    2875    &   4.19    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.6 $\pm$   0.02    &   4.4 $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.37    $\pm$   0.01    &   13.65   $\pm$   0.24    &   267 &   4   \\  \hline
    
    Si IV   &   1.99    $\pm$   0.1 &   1.53    $\pm$   0.08    &   1.76    $\pm$   0.09    &   19.24   &   1.3 $\pm$   0.09    &   14.21   $\pm$   3.04    &   267 &   3   \\  
    C IV    &   6.13    $\pm$   0.1 &   6.41    $\pm$   0.06    &   6.27    $\pm$   0.08    &   73.39   &   1.05    $\pm$   0.02    &   2.34    $\pm$   0.85    &   267 &   3   \\  
    
    C III]  &   1.85    $\pm$   0.07    &   6.38    $\pm$   0.06    &   4.12    $\pm$   0.07    &   40.66   &   0.52    $\pm$   0.19    &   70.91   $\pm$   1.1 &   0.26    &   6   \\  
    
    Mg II   &   0.98    $\pm$   0.05    &   0.79    $\pm$   0.05    &   0.89    $\pm$   0.05    &   16.42   &   1.45    $\pm$   0.12    &   19.02   $\pm$   3.57    &   63  &   3   \\  \hline\hline
    
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1982}               &               &       &       \\      
    
    1350    &   10.57   $\pm$   0.03    &   10.58   $\pm$   0.04    &   10.58   $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.06    $\pm$   0.01    &   3.49    $\pm$   0.21    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
    
    1450    &   9.32    $\pm$   0.06    &   8.93    $\pm$   0.07    &   9.13    $\pm$   0.07    &   -   &   1.16    $\pm$   0.01    &   7.41    $\pm$   0.43    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    1605    &   10.46   $\pm$   0.06    &   9.98    $\pm$   0.06    &   10.22   $\pm$   0.06    &   -   &   1.18    $\pm$   0.01    &   8.29    $\pm$   0.32    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                
    1675    &   9.26    $\pm$   0.03    &   8.31    $\pm$   0.04    &   8.79    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   0.9 $\pm$   0.01    &   10.97   $\pm$   0.26    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                        
    1812    &   7.71    $\pm$   0.03    &   7.2 $\pm$   0.02    &   7.46    $\pm$   0.03    &   -   &   1.13    $\pm$   0.01    &   6.16    $\pm$   0.23    &   0.26    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                
    Si IV   &   2.38    $\pm$   0.09    &   1.97    $\pm$   0.08    &   2.18    $\pm$   0.09    &   24.88   &   1.21    $\pm$   0.07    &   9.72    $\pm$   2.32    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   6.73    $\pm$   0.08    &   6.37    $\pm$   0.07    &   6.55    $\pm$   0.08    &   87.18   &   1.16    $\pm$   0.02    &   7.79    $\pm$   0.66    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    He II   &   2.39    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.65    $\pm$   0.08    &   2.52    $\pm$   0.08    &   37.91   &   1.34    $\pm$   0.06    &   15.11   $\pm$   1.54    &   0.14    &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C III]  &   3.29    $\pm$   0.06    &   1.08    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.19    $\pm$   0.07    &   25.5    &   3.14    $\pm$   0.22    &   60.26   $\pm$   2.12    &   0.07    &   4   \\  \hline\hline
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
    &       $\pm$       &       $\pm$       &                   &   \textbf{1985}       &       &       $\pm$       &       &       \\      
                                                                                                                    
    C III]  &   2.3 $\pm$   0.05    &   7.58    $\pm$   0.04    &   4.94    $\pm$   0.05    &   81.88   &   4.78    $\pm$   0.11    &   85.59   $\pm$   0.95    &   174 &   3   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   7   $\pm$   0.06    &   10.81   $\pm$   0.05    &   8.91    $\pm$   0.06    &   153.07  &   1.54    $\pm$   0.01    &   23.7    $\pm$   0.41    &   174 &   3   \\  \hline \hline
                                                                                                                    
    &               &               &                   &   \textbf{1989}               &               &       &       \\      
                                                                                                                    
    1350    &   12.03   $\pm$   0.03    &   9.24    $\pm$   0.02    &   10.64   $\pm$   0.03    &   -   &   1.49    $\pm$   0.01    &   15.27   $\pm$   0.11    &   182 &   10  \\  
    1450    &   10.91   $\pm$   0.06    &   9.5 $\pm$   0.05    &   10.21   $\pm$   0.06    &   -   &   1.39    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.16   $\pm$   0.22    &   182 &   7   \\  
    1605    &   12.29   $\pm$   0.05    &   9   $\pm$   0.04    &   10.65   $\pm$   0.05    &   -   &   1.53    $\pm$   0.01    &   13.27   $\pm$   0.14    &   182 &   10  \\  
    1675    &   10.15   $\pm$   0.04    &   8.33    $\pm$   0.03    &   9.24    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   0.82    $\pm$   0   &   12.89   $\pm$   0.12    &   182 &   11  \\  
                                                                                                                    
    1812    &   9.87    $\pm$   0.05    &   7.44    $\pm$   0.03    &   8.66    $\pm$   0.04    &   -   &   1.63    $\pm$   0.01    &   14.18   $\pm$   0.13    &   182 &   11  \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2475    &   6.51    $\pm$   0.02    &   5.38    $\pm$   0.01    &   5.95    $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.31    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.32   $\pm$   0.14    &   182 &   6   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2625    &   5.72    $\pm$   0.02    &   4.88    $\pm$   0.01    &   5.3 $\pm$   0.02    &   -   &   1.24    $\pm$   0.01    &   8.91    $\pm$   0.12    &   182 &   6   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    2875    &   5.04    $\pm$   0.01    &   4.18    $\pm$   0.01    &   4.61    $\pm$   0.01    &   -   &   1.29    $\pm$   0   &   11.12   $\pm$   0.25    &   182 &   6   \\  \hline
                                                                                                                    
    Ly$\alpha$  &   14.37   $\pm$   0.04    &   13.2    $\pm$   0.1 &   13.79   $\pm$   0.07    &   176.69  &   1.43    $\pm$   0.01    &   11.4    $\pm$   0.22    &   182 &   9   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    Si IV   &   1.82    $\pm$   0.08    &   3.08    $\pm$   0.07    &   2.45    $\pm$   0.08    &   24.36   &   2.12    $\pm$   0.1 &   26.58   $\pm$   1.63    &   29  &   7   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    C IV    &   6.32    $\pm$   0.06    &   6.26    $\pm$   0.09    &   6.29    $\pm$   0.08    &   93.79   &   1.33    $\pm$   0.02    &   9.79    $\pm$   0.38    &   58  &   9   \\  
                                                                                                                    
    He II   &   3.16    $\pm$   0.08    &   4.1 $\pm$   0.05    &   3.63    $\pm$   0.07    &   42.14   &   2.24    $\pm$   0.06    &   28.59   $\pm$   0.95    &   29  &   7   \\  
            
    C III]  &   3.96    $\pm$   0.06    &   1.19    $\pm$   0.09    &   2.58    $\pm$   0.08    &   19.66   &   5.49    $\pm$   0.43    &   71.22   $\pm$   1.87    &   54  &   9   \\  
            
    Mg II   &   2.55    $\pm$   0.04    &   1.2 $\pm$   0.04    &   1.88    $\pm$   0.04    &   31.24   &   3.03    $\pm$   0.11    &   42.57   $\pm$   1.25    &   54  &   7   \\  \hline\hline
    
        \end{longtable} 

    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]